# Реализация ненулевого члена класса

Tags: ооп, c++

Здравствуйте, у меня есть некий класс, содержащий в себе член, который, согласно условиям решаемой задачи, никогда не должен быть равен нулю.
Я подумал и решил реализовать этот член с помощью следующего класса:

```
class Nonnullable
{
    unsigned short i;
    void setting(unsigned short n)
    {
        if(!(i=n))i=1;
    }
    public:
    Nonnullable()
    {
        setting(1);
    }
    Nonnullable(unsigned short n)
    {
        setting(n);
    }
    operator unsigned short()
    {
        return i;
    }
    Nonnullable & operator = (const unsigned short & n)
    {
        setting(n);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Хотелось бы услышать вашу оценку такого способа решения проблемы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот код, который вы написали решает *очень узкоспециализированную* задачу, а именно предоставляет концепт non-nullable обертки для `unsigned short`. И, кстати говоря, решает задачу не совсем правильно, хотя, вероятно, допустимо для вашего конкретного случая.

---

**Перед тем, как начинать реализацию концепта такого рода, необходимо для себя ответить на следующие вопросы:**

- Является ли реализовываемый концепт `nonnullable` одновременно и `default-initializable`, т.е имеет ли объект `nonnullable<T>` какое либо изначальное значение или оно не определено? *В своем текущем коде вы неявно ответили "да" на второй вопрос, тем самым пойдя вразрез со стандартным поведением примитивных типов в языке `C++`, т.е, одновременно объединили два концепта.* Откуда, кстати говоря, взялось стандартное значение `1`, совершенно непонятно.
- Для каких типов предусматривается данный концепт - примитивных, POD, ссылочных и т.п. Как это соотносится с ответом на первый вопрос и каким должно быть дефолтное значение, если вы объединяете два разных концепта.
- Необходимо ли предусматривать возможность неявного конструирования типа `nonnullable<T>` из произвольно взятого объекта и каким должно быть поведение в случае, если это конструирование является недопустимой операцией?
- Допускать ли возможность неявного преобразования типа `nonnullable<T>` в `T` и каким должно быть поведение в случае, если на первый вопрос был дан положительный ответ?

---

**Допустим, что для конкретной задачи я ответил на эти вопросы следующим образом:**

- Да, выбранный тип предусматривает инициализацию стандартным значением, при этом это самое стандартное значение является аналогом `null` для этого типа, т.е **недопустимым**. Это поведение коррелирует со стандартным поведением примитивных типов в `C++`, которые не инициализируются по умолчанию, а значит являются *невалидными.* Таким образом, следующий код (`T` - некоторый примитивный тип): `nonnullable<T> x;` оставляет `x` в невалидном состоянии.2
- Данный тип предусмотрен только для примитивных типов, при этом определение примитивного типа берется из стандарта C++03 / 0x, а на практике реализуется с использованием `boost::is_fundamental` или `std::is_fundamental` в новом стандарте.
- Да, при этом попытка конструирования данного типа из его аналога `null` приводит к исключению.
- Да, поведение аналогично (3).

---

**Набросок реализации может выглядеть следующим образом:**

```
template <typename T> class fundamental_nonnullable {

    boost::static_assert(boost::is_fundamental<T>::value, "This concept can only be applied to fundamental types.");

public:
    fundamental_nonnullable() : holder_(null_value<T>()) { }

    fundamental_nonnullable(T value) {
        if (!is_valid(value))
            throw std::invalid_argument(...);

        holder_ = value;
    }

    operator T() const {
        if (!is_valid(holder_))
            throw std::invalid_argument(...);

        return holder_;
    }

private:
    // Допускает переопределение для любого примитивного типа.
    template <typename Y> static Y null_value() { return 0; }
    // Например, так:
    // template <> static float null_value<float>() { return 69.0f; }

    // Аналогично можно переопределить для любых примитивных типов.
    template <typename Y> static bool is_valid(Y value) {
        return value != null_value<Y>(); 
    }

private:
    T holder_;
}
```

---

Понятно, что все вышесказанное - это лишь информация к размышлению, но примерно из таких соображений и рождаются хитроумные и интересные концепты в шаблонных библиотеках типа `boost`, которые потом переходят в стандартную библиотеку C++.

---

**Еще вопросы для размышления:**

- Каким образом "заворачивать" в объект `nonnullable<T>` ссылочные и pointer типы?
- Как должно соотносится время жизни `nonnullable` объекта со временем жизни исходного (большей частью, если мы используем smart указатели и любые механизмы подсчета ссылок)?
- Каким образом `SFINAE` может быть использовано для улучшения кода данного концепта?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал выброс исключения, при попытке присвоить ноль, а не тихо менял 0 на 1. А в клиентском коде уже бы проверял перед присваиванием. Иначе могут возникнуть непонятные для пользователя эффекты. 
Например был у вас такой код:

```
Nonnullable res;
....
res = func();
if (res == 1) {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
}
```

тут все нормально. Потом внезапно функция f стала возвращать 0 в случае ошибки. Вы быстренько вносите изменения:

```
if (res == 0) {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
}
```

и получаете труднонаходимую ошибку.

Comment: Может, тогда в `func()` бросать исключение? Если ошибка в функции, а исключение где-то еще, тоже не очень понятно.

Comment: @bipll, функция про Nonnullable может ничего не знать (и вообще быть библиотечной).

Comment: Вполне, тогда зачем она использует 0 в качестве ошибки? Это non-idiomatic C++ way.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы в функции `setting` не добавить противоположное условие, присваивая `i=1` вместо того, чтобы в каждом конструкторе это делать?

Comment: Спасибо, подкорректировал. А сам подход вы считаете правильным? Не лучше ли, например, использовать unsigned short вместо Nonnullable и пытаться вводить какие-то  средства для контроля, в класс, содержащий, этот член? Или ещё каким-то другим образом это сделать?